# Mechanism to transfer power between a button on a panel and a button several inches distant

Tags: mechanical-engineering

I have an application where a single board computer similar to a Raspberry Pi is rigidly mounted inside a box.  There is a power button on the board that I want to press "remotely" by pressing a button on the outside of the box.

Our previous solution for this problem is failing due to the holes in the boxes not always aligning 100% according to spec.  I was wondering whether there might be something like a remote shutter release cable (allowing flexibility in where the button on the box is mounted) that could be mounted on the wall of the box and connected to the button on the board in such a way that pressing the outside button presses the inside button.

A stiff, extended plunger seems like it would be prone to alignment difficulty.

If this is an x/y problem, I'm also open to other suggestions.

[image: picture of situation]

Answer (score 7):

Another solution in this case might be to get a new button that you can mount on the panel and then use extension wires to solder/connect it to the pins of the reset button.

[image]

I'm mainly proposing this, because you seem quite confident with the electronic side of things.

Comment: This will provide the most reliable operation by a long shot - a switch on flying leads is the correct answer as far as I’m concerned

Comment: I dont think you need to you can acess same thing internally too. Or atleast you could in v1 and2 boards

Comment: @joojaa could you expand on what you're saying here?